# Replicate each column for certain times

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe as follows:

```r
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:3, A = c(2, 0, 1), B = c(0, 3, 2))

#   ID A B
# 1  1 2 0
# 2  2 0 3
# 3  3 1 2
```

I want to replicate each column for `N` times where `N` means the maximum in that column. The column names are filled into the replicated columns for corresponding times and aligned left.

The expected output:

```
#   ID  A1    A2    B1    B2    B3   
# 1  1  A     A     NA    NA    NA   
# 2  2  NA    NA    B     B     B    
# 3  3  A     NA    B     B     NA
```

I prefer `base` or `tidyverse` solutions. `data.table` is welcome but I'm unfamiliar to it though.

Thanks for any helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `tidyr` solution with `uncount()` duplicating rows according to each number in the data:

```r
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-ID) %>%
  uncount(value) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = ID, values_from = name, values_fn = list, names_sort = TRUE) %>%
  unnest_wider(-ID, names_sep = '')

# # A tibble: 3 × 6
#      ID A1    A2    B1    B2    B3   
#   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1     1 A     A     NA    NA    NA   
# 2     2 NA    NA    B     B     B    
# 3     3 A     NA    B     B     NA
```

Comment: I don’t understand it but it surely looks interesting.

Answer (score 4):

With `rep` + `unnest_wider`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(A:B, \(x) sapply(x, \(y) rep(cur_column(), y)))) %>% 
  unnest_wider(A:B, names_sep = "")

#   ID   A1   A2   B1   B2   B3
# 1  1    A    A <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 2  2 <NA> <NA>    B    B    B
# 3  3    A <NA>    B    B <NA>
```

An alternative with `strrep` + `strsplit`:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(across(A:B, \(x) strsplit(strrep(cur_column(), x), ""))) %>% 
  unnest_wider(A:B, names_sep = "")
```